# How can I delete file extensions of all files in an array?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

When the mac osx app runs, it will create an array that contains the NSString names and extensions for all the files in a directory. However, I want to delete the file extensions from each file in the array before I display them to the user and place these names in an array. How can I accomplish this?

ex. picture.jpeg, image.jpeg, and picture2.png to picture, image, and picture2

Comment: Regular Expressions http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm is one way.

Comment: I think if you make some research you can do this yourself man, if you struggle comeback with the code.

Comment: You might want to look at [NSFileManager displayNameAtPath: ](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000305-CJBJDAHH)

Comment: Your edited-in sentence makes absolutely no sense. You can't do _anything at all_ "until after the program begins execution". How do you get it to work? Call it on the strings in the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `stringByDeletingPathExtension` and KVC collection operators:

```
NSArray *original = @[@"picture.jpeg", @"image.jpeg", @"picture2.png"];
NSArray *modified = [original valueForKeyPath:@"stringByDeletingPathExtension"];
```

Here `valueForKeyPath` returns an array containing the result of calling `stringByDeletingPathExtension` on all objects in the array.

Answer (score 1):

NSString's – stringByDeletingPathExtension should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 1):

[`-[NSString stringByDeletingPathExtension]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByDeletingPathExtension) is what you're looking for.